# Layout: center image inside center panel. Using percent units

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, design-guidelines

I am trying to get a desing similar to the following in one of my Activities layout:

[image]

That is:

- A white panel with 60% width of its parent. Center horizontally.
- Inside that white panel, a image with 60% width of the panel, center
  horizontally too.

I have been playing with Guidelines putting them at 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 and 0.8 horizonatlly without success.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a ConstraintLayout as the root layout, then set the width of your child to 0dp and width percent to .6 (this for the first container, 60%):

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/some_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".6" >
```

For the ImageView, it is 60% of a viewgroup that itself is 60%, so it needs to be 36% of the parent:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/some_other_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".36" />
```

Another option is to make the ImageView parent a ConstraintLayout and then set the width of the ImageView to 60%, but that way your layout won't be flat.